# React Router - how to route users to the page that they just came from?

Tags: reactjs

I apologize if this is the first thing on the React Router documentation, I had a hard time piecing stuff together.

**I have a few protected routes, clicking on them without being logged in routes them to the login page, but after successfully pressing the login button, I want them to return to the protected route that they just came from **

Ex. clicks on /user_only => loginForm => login successfully => route to /user_only

This is my code of routing after the successful login press (go to /home)

```
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/home"); // push user to dashboard when they login
    }
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
    console.log(nextProps.errors);
  }
```

But instead of this.props.history.push("/home"), I want to push to wherever the user just came from.

I remember a react router property named "from" may solve my problem (I have no idea what it does but intuitively it appears to be the url that the user came from), but I am unable to find where I once came across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reliable way to do is to create a PrivateRoute higher order component for all your protected routes, to capture the private path route that the user initially lands on and to handle redirects to a login page if the user is not authenticated.

This path can then be stored as a url param which the login route would use to redirect the user post authentication.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  let redirectUrl = '';
  if (rest.location.pathname !== '/') {
    const redirectPathName = rest.location.pathname;
    const redirectParams = rest.location.search;
    redirectUrl = `redirectUrl=${encodeURIComponent(`${redirectPathName}${redirectParams}`)}`;
  }
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => sessionStorage.token ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', search: redirectUrl }} />}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter(PrivateRoute);
```

**Login.js**

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const Login = ({ history }) => {
  const onLogin = () => {
    const isAuthenticatd = false;

    // Perform authentication here and if authentication is successfull

    const queryParams = queryString.parse(history.location.search)
    if (isAuthenticatd && queryParams.redirectUrl) {
      history.push(queryParams.redirectUrl);
    } else {
      history.push('path to default landing page post authentication');
    }
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={onLogin} />
  );
};

export default withRouter(Login);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import PrivateRoute from '/path/to/privateroute/component';
import YourPrivateComponent from '/path/to/component';
import Login from '/path/to/Login';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute path="yourPrivatePath" component={YourPrivateComponent} />
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note: `PrivateRoute` and `Login` must be wrapped with `withRouter` Hoc from `react-router` to have access to `location.pathname`.

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score -1):

Hmm I just saw a man posting the answer but then deleting it for some reason. Anyways, he answered with **this.props.history.goBack()**, I think the only potential bug with that right now is if the user directly go to "/loginForm", you can't goBack() without anywhere to back. I am certain that there must be some field containing the previous URL, and just do `if prev == null then this.props.history.push("home")`. I will update this answer when I find the prop of history that does that.